# How to fix wrong path for flask on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

installed flask jsonDash on windows 10.
When starting app receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/WORK/mc-metrics/mc_app/app.py", line 17, in <module>
app.register_blueprint(charts)
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 64, in      wrapper_func
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 951, in register_blueprint
blueprint.register(self, options, first_registration)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\blueprints.py", line 151, in register
endpoint='static')
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\blueprints.py", line 76, in add_url_rule
view_func, defaults=defaults, **options)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 64, in wrapper_func
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1043, in add_url_rule
rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 603, in __init__
raise ValueError('urls must start with a leading slash')
ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash
```

app.py

```
"""This is an example app, demonstrating usage."""

 import os

 from flask import Flask

 from flask_jsondash.charts_builder import charts

  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'NOTSECURELOL'
  app.config.update(
JSONDASH_FILTERUSERS=False,
JSONDASH_GLOBALDASH=True,
JSONDASH_GLOBAL_USER='global',
)
app.debug = True
app.register_blueprint(charts)   //when I comment it it starts server


def _can_edit_global():
   return True


def _can_delete():
   return True


def _can_clone():
   return True


def _get_username():
   return 'anonymous'


# Config examples.
app.config['JSONDASH'] = dict(
metadata=dict(
    created_by=_get_username,
    username=_get_username,
),
static=dict(
    js_path='js/vendor/',
    css_path='css/vendor/',
),
auth=dict(
    edit_global=_can_edit_global,
    clone=_can_clone,
    delete=_can_delete,
)
```

)

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
"""Sample index."""
return '<a href="/charts">Visit the charts blueprint.</a>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
PORT = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080))
HOST = os.getenv('HOST', '0.0.0.0')
app.run(debug=True, host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

I used code form here https://github.com/christabor/flask_jsondash

Seems like issue with patth differance linux and windows. How to solve it? Thank you very much in advance

Some extra info.form debugger:
    [image]

Comment: It must be you miss a leading slash when you define a route map use `app.route`.

Comment: how to fix it? I am very very new...

Answer (score 1):

When you define the url make sure it's start with `'/'`

```
@app.route('/landing-page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def landing_page():
    return "Landing Page"
```

If I construct the route without `/` like `@app.route('landing-page')` then the error.

Comment: updated. you can take a look at app. Actually it was coned from repo.

Comment: I can see `Visit the charts blueprint.`

Comment: I get connection refused error `ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused` when I clicked that link

Comment: @Serhiy Is that full error traceback? Can you update with full traceback from the console ?

Comment: Hi updated. there is something to do with app.register_blueprint(charts)
when I comment the line -server starts...seems like it sends wrong path..?

Comment: May be... Can you check the charts `Blueprint` define ?

Comment: On local fixed. Ofcource not so good way, but at least I needed it on local:
in Lib\site-packages\flask\blueprints.py
commented:
 # if self.has_static_folder:
        #     state.add_url_rule(self.static_url_path + '/<path:filename>',
        #                        view_func=self.send_static_file,
        #                        endpoint='static')

Comment: I think you can escalate this to https://github.com/christabor/flask_jsondash create a new issue over there.